# how to work with south in django

Tags: django

I am trying to learn about python-django web framework.
I have successfully installed database migration tool 'south' in my ubuntu os and also added it to `INSTALLED_APPS` for using this tool for my web app.

When I run any command using manage.py like

```
$ ./manage.py runserver
```

I get this error:

```
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/South-1.0.2-py2.7.egg/south/db/generic.py:9: RemovedInDjango19Warning: The django.db.backends.util module has been renamed. Use django.db.backends.utils instead.
  from django.db.backends.util import truncate_name

There is no South database module 'south.db.sqlite3' for your database. Please either choose a supported database, check for SOUTH_DATABASE_ADAPTER[S] settings, or remove South from INSTALLED_APPS."
```

I don't understand what it means. How can I fix this error?

Please give your useful suggestion to solve this error.Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you appear to be using the development version of Django. Don't do that, especially as you're just beginning. Use the latest actual release, 1.8.

Secondly, since 1.7 Django has included built-in migrations. There is no need to install South.

Comment: Also, try the migration docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/).